# Double integral of a function

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate:

$$J = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \, dx .$$

I tried the substitutions $u=x-y$ and $v=x+y$ and found $J=1/2$, $0 \leq v \leq 2$ and $-1 \leq u \leq 1$ but found $J=0$.  Is my way of thinking correct?

Comment: See the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to reformat your question to make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your beneficial advice. I would appreciate for your quidance.

Comment: Just so you can check yourself:  the answer is $1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

This double integral does not converge absolutely, and so the answer will depend upon how we interpret and calculate it.

If we treat is as literally the iterated integral in that order, we obtain
$$
\int\limits_0^1 \bigg( \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \bigg) \, dx = \int\limits_0^1 \bigg( \dfrac{y}{(x+y)^2} \bigg|_0^1 \bigg) \, dx = \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2} \, dx = \frac{-1}{x+1} \bigg|_0^1 = \frac12.
$$
However, if we try to calculate the iterated integral in the opposite order, we get a different answer:
$$
\int\limits_0^1 \bigg( \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx \bigg) \, dy = \int\limits_0^1 \bigg( \dfrac{-x}{(x+y)^2} \bigg|_0^1 \bigg) \, dy = \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{-1}{(y+1)^2} \, dy = \frac{1}{y+1} \bigg|_0^1 = -\frac12.
$$
And other ways of evaluating the integral would lead to other answers as well—for example, interchanging the variables $x$ and $y$ preserves the region of integration but negates the integrand, which (if valid) would lead to $J=-J$ and thus $J=0$.

So in this case, we don't have free reign to use any technique we want to evaluate the integral—we have to evaluate it as given to us (the first calculation above).

Comment: Thank you very much!